# gstreamer + framebuffer и вывод его на QWidget

Tags: c++, linux, qt5

Вот сколько уже пытаюсь вытащить видео с камеры на QWidget, пробовал QMultimedia (1-2 fps), пробовал на прямую в QPixmap через gstreamer + appsink, 2-3 fps... Много всего в общем)) железо не мощное. Теперь пробую так:

1) запихиваю с помощью gstreamer и fbdevsink видео во framebuffer (/dev/fb1)

2)  получаю оттуда изображение и вывожу его на widget.

С первым пунктом проблем нет...
Чем можно выполнить второй пункт? Вроде как QScreen но ума не хватает с ним разобраться. 
Еще слышал про directFB - но что это за зверь такой? и как его вообще использовать на QT?

**P.S.** Если просто выводить видео через gstreamer без привязки к виджету, оно летает! загрузка процессора ~3%

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться QGraphicView + QOpenGLWidget. Когда-то давно пробовал использовать для написания тестовой игры. На сцену(scene) добавляются графические элементы. Тогда всё это плавно работало.

```
CGraphicsView *view = new CGraphicsView(); 
CGraphicsScene *scene = new CGraphicsScene();
view->setScene(scene);

view->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
view->setViewport(new QOpenGLWidget());
view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```